# How do I determine the nominal memory bandwidth of my system?

Tags: memory, hardware, bandwidth

I'm running some (not so new) Linux distribution. I want to determine what the memory bandwidth of my system is - not the effective bandwidth I can get from benchmarking/testing - but the *nominal* bandwidth, given my board, CPU sockets, memory channels and RAM DIMMs.

I should mention that when I try to figure this out in my head I always get the calculations mixed up: gigabytes verus gigabits, transactions per seconds vs bytes per second, the number of channels vs the number of DIMMs etc.

Note: If possible, assume I don't have utilities such as lshw or inxi installed.

Comment: What for? What are you trying to solve? What will this information give to you? memtest86 shows it very well.

Comment: For accessing big amounts of RAM you can neglect the effects of caching and the bottleneck will typically be the bandwidth to the RAM. Multiply your memory clock with the width of the memory bus and factor 2 for DDR and you have your theoretical bandwidth. What is the U&L relation of the question?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: (4.) I don't have physical access to the machine and can't run something like memtest86 on it. (1.+2.) I want to determine the memory bandwidth. (3.) It will let me know how far the measured bandwidth I see (e.g. with [pcm](https://github.com/opcm/pcm) is from the nominal bandwidth. Also, different values on different systems will give me an idea of what differences to expect in actual bandwidths.

Comment: @Philippos: But if I have N sockets, that should be another multiplicative factor, should it not? As you  have N memory controllers, each being able to drive the same bandwidth as a complete single-socket system to/from its associated DIMMs. Right?

Comment: @einpoklum You are probably right. I'm an embedded guy, I never met such a system, so I don't know if this could move the bottleneck to some other layer.

Answer (score 0):

what you are technically asking is not necessarily easy to explain here as a complete answer, to tell you how to do the math to get a *nominal* performance number based on hardware capabilities.  You would have to get the hardware (motherboard) model number and look up the specs from the manufacturer and then, if they do publish the numbers you're looking for, do some paper calculations yourself.

If you don't have physical access to the machine, a first step would be to run `dmidecode` and use the information reported from that along with the internet to gather information.

`dmidecode` output and capability may vary between linux distributions and hardware, but under RHEL-7.9 and a dell server it shows me bios version, cpu information, voltage and clock speeds, and every DIMM slot and if it is populated or not along with the RAM model and serial number and voltage, for example:

```
Handle 0x1129, DMI type 17, 84 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 32 GB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 7
    Locator: D6
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Registered (Buffered)
    Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Manufacturer: 00AD063200AD
    Serial Number: 123456
    Asset Tag: 123456
    Part Number: HMA84GR7JJR4N-WM
    Rank: 2
    Configured Memory Speed: 2933 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
    Memory Technology: DRAM
    Memory Operating Mode Capability: Volatile memory
    Firmware Version: Not Specified
    Module Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Module Product ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Manufacturer ID: Unknown
    Memory Subsystem Controller Product ID: Unknown
    Non-Volatile Size: None
    Volatile Size: 32 GB
    Cache Size: None
    Logical Size: None
```

from information like, of which from my server there are 48 DIMM outputs from dmidecode where only 24 are populated with RAM, is what I think you would use to come up with as a *nominal bandwidth*, or theoretical max bandwidth? number.  Which is not necessarily easy, and like was said in comments may not be all that realistic given all the various bottlenecks and what not that can happen... which is where/why you would run a **real-time** linux kernel so there is consistency and repeatability if you are interested in that sort of thing.

Comment: 1. Why would the exact Motherboard model matter here? 2. I know the nominal/theoretical bandwidth may not be achievable in practice, but it's still what I want to measure. You say this would not be easy; why? Is it more than a simple formula, which a novice programmer could write a small script to compute?

Comment: your subject says nominal, not sure what actually means in this context, and you mention doing calculations.  In order to do calculations correctly, you need correct information... from the manufacturer, of the given model motherboard, which you may or may not get entirely from `dmidecode` in linux.  Or just download/buy a memory bandwidth benchmark utility and see what it reports, but like was mentioned can vary based on operating system configuration and bottlenecks as they come and go.  But what the benchmark reports may be far below the theoretical max, whic you would have to calculate.

Comment: https://github.com/intel/memory-bandwidth-benchmarks

Comment: **STREAM**  ... https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ref.html

Comment: for a cluster having infiniband (i.e. 200gbps) and using RDMA and many nodes, calculating what an acceptable memory bandwidth between 100 nodes all running simultaneously is daunting, usually just run a benchmark and everything is consistent call it good don't know how they sit a minimum achievable threshold.  On a simple pc workstation it is much easier to calculate, based on motherboard and ram specs.  What you are asking... nomimal or maximum memory bandwidth... is hardware related and should be independent of the linux distribution being used.

Comment: but if one linux distro benchmarks better than another then you have a relative comparison between just that, but you still don't know what a nominal or max benchmark number should be until you calculate it or is reported by the motherboard maker which is based on the hardware.

Comment: *I'm running some (not so new) Linux distribution.* ... get a few spare disks and install various new free linux distro's like centos, mint, debian, and then run STREAM and compare the benchmark to your not so new linux distro to see where it stands.  That's probably the best way to know, if that's possible for you to do.  Otherwise you're left to calculating that number and do you trust yourself or someone else to do the calculations correctly, gonna be wrong way before being close to correct.

Comment: nominal != actual. The bandwidth the system is _supposed_ to have given its hardware configuration. Naturally, benchmarking software is not relevant here.